# How are upstream changelogs pulled and shared in Debian?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I know that in Debian you have a watch file which diffs the pristine version of a package with a release upstream (using regexp) and telling if there is a new package release. How are changelogs done. Are they imported manually or is there some dh (debhelper) magic which automates most of the work, something like diffing between changelog numbers and adding the recent changes. The source could either be in some git repository which has a file called changelog or a tarball which has a file called changelog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upstream changelogs aren’t imported specifically, they are handled as a file in the upstream source code. There is a `debhelper` helper, [`dh_installchangelogs`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/debhelper/dh_installchangelogs.1), which handles Debian-specific changelogs and upstream changelogs. Package maintainers don’t have to use this of course, theyways handle changelogs in other ways.

Packages are always built in isolation, they can’t compare files to the previous version.